# Ensure sequential items are selected in checklistbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, checklistbox

I have a checklistbox which has some sequentially items, when i click on items from it and click on submit button all items should gets store in database.

But here i want to ensure user selects sequential items only, like user cannot be able to select a,b,d,f they should always be selecting a,b,c,d,e,f.

Can anyone please suggest me the logic to accomplish this.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the user attempts to select a,b,d,f? Should be allowed but get an error message? Should you block selecting d? Should you auto-select c when he selects d and auto-select e when he selects f? You need to explain what you want to happen.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do with the single loop as below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < chkBox.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                if (chkBox.Items[i].Selected)
                {
                    if (chkBox.Items[i - 1].Selected)
                        continue;
                    else
                    {
                        _isSequentialSelected = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

First it will loop through all the items, once the loop is on second item and its selected, it will go on and check if the previous item was selected, if previous item was selected, it will continue, else it will be break the loop flagging a bool variable false and then outside loop i can easily check if the flag is true or false and accordingly show message.

Comment: What if the last item is `-1`? And what if only one value is selected?

Comment: As you can see i have used if (i>0) before making a sequential check, so if only one item is selected it will be a success no check is required on it.

Comment: It will save you in the case if first item is selected, I was asking if user selects lets say it is `4`, then your code will check if `3` was selected or not, and will result in `false`.

Comment: But i don't want to allow them to select any items from the middle, else what will be use of sequential check, they have to select all items from first in sequential order.

Comment: Then its fine. You didn't explain this case before.

Comment: Actually i said they should not be allowed a,b,d,f and should always be in sequental like a,b,c,d,e,f. i didn't mention they can select anything from middle so that could not be in test case either, anyways thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the best logic, but it does the job at-least:

```
List<int> selectedvalues = new List<int>();
bool isSequence = true;

//get all selected indices
for(int i = 0; i < checkboxlist.Items.Count; i++)
    if(checkboxlist.Items[i].Selected)
        selectedvalues.Add(i);

//start from first selected index, go to last selected index
for(int i = selectedvalues[0]; i < selectedvalues[selectedvalues.Length - 1]; i++)
    if(i != selectedvalues[i])
    {
        isSequence = false;
        break;
    }
```

**1st test case:**

```
User selected indices: 3, 4, 7, 8
Now second loop:
    i = 3, index = 3
    i = 4, index = 4
    i = 5, index = 7    //false and break
```

**2nd test case:**

```
User selected indices: 3, 4, 5, 6
Now second loop:
    i = 3, index = 3
    i = 4, index = 4
    i = 5, index = 5
    i = 6, index = 6    //success
```

PS: I have not compiled this code, if you get any error please let me know.